# In eclipse, how can I enable auto insert of closing }}?

Tags: django, eclipse

I'm using eclipse for **python/django** work. One annoyance is that when in html editor, when I enter **{%** or **{{**, eclipse doesn't auto-complete the closing **%}**, **}}** since those aren't html tags.

I read about the templates and content assists. It seems like templates is the way to go, but can't seem to get mine to work.

**How can I enable the this:**

> 1) enter {{
>
> 2) eclipse auto-inserts }} so that we have {{ _ }} with insertion point automatically within the {{ }}.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Aptana Studio](http://aptana.com/). A special distribution of Eclipse that will autocomplete that for you.

It has better support for WebBased scripting languages such as Python (DJANGO), Ruby (Rails), PHP and many others.

You can download and install it from scratch, or just upgrade your current Eclipse installation with it.

Comment: Eclipse+PyDev is functionally equivalent to Aptana Studio. AFAIK there's nothing special in Aptana Studio's implementation of PyDev.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: I see... You sure? Even DJANGO/JINJA2 template support is in PYDEV?

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. My thinking came from the fact that everything python related in Aptana comes from PyDev. However, the Django templating portion in PyDev is only compatible with Aptana.